# CheckedBoxList SelectedItemChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I have CheckedBoxList and when I click on one element, I don't want it to be checked (CheckedOnClick = false) but I would like to do an action (Show information about this SelectedItem on an other element of my Form)

I didn't find anything on a similar thing of ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged for CheckedListBox.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the [CheckedListBox.ItemCheck Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) which

> Occurs when the checked state of an item changes.

or the [ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) which the `CheckedListBox` inherits from the `ListBox`.

**Inheritance Hierarchy**

> System.Object
>
> System.MarshalByRefObject
>
> System.ComponentModel.Component
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Control
>
> System.Windows.Forms.ListControl
>
> System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
>
> System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox

You can check the [CheckedListBox Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx) list, it's there. So unless you are using some kind of 3rd party control it should be available.
[image]

Comment: What i'm understanding about your link :
This event will be called if I check an element and not if i select an element, right ?

I would like and event which :
Occurs when the selected state of an item changes.

Comment: Yes... however I must admit I'm not sure if this is really what you asked.

Comment: I'll check that later but I think you answered to my question (and I'll mark as answered if yes).